# SQL server, linked server error with open query

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I can't figure out why I am getting this error on the open query line:

"Could not find server 'Server_Name' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers."

When I run the code in parts it works...

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE name = Server_Name)

BEGIN

        EXEC sys.sp_addlinkedserver
                @server = Server_Name, @srvproduct = 'SQL Server'
        EXEC sys.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
                Server_Name, 'FALSE', NULL, 'username', 'password'
END

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Server_Name, 'select * from table')


IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE name = Server_Name)

        EXEC sys.sp_dropserver @server = Server_Name, @droplogins = 'droplogins'
```

Comment: I think you need a `GO;` in between the `END` and your first `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY`

Comment: @tommy_o
Thanks that was it.